# Plotting an approximated Dirac Comb

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to approximate a *Dirac Comb* to use in an [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) calculation but when I `Plot` it over a large interval, it misses peaks out and they are not all of the same height (it works fine for a small interval). I have a feeling this is a sampling error but I don't know how to change this.

```
ϵ = 0.0001;
θz[t_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(i = 1\), \(120\)]
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(E\), 
FractionBox[\(-\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((t - i)\), \(2\)]\), \(4  ϵ\)]], \(2 
\*SqrtBox[\(ϵ*π\)]\)]\);
Plot[θz[t], {t, 0, 120}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: As you say, this is `Plot` sampling too coarsely when plotting. If you plot with the command `Plot[\[Theta]z[t], {t, 0, 120}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 10]`, you will see more spikes and they are the same height, but still a lot will be missing. Increasing further will take more time and hopefully show more spikes. Adding `PlotPoints -> 100` or something should also help. But there is nothing wrong with your function, so don't worry :)

Comment: Up to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) , this plot has no sense in traditional math. Maybe, you make use of some nontraditional math. In this case, please give us references.

Comment: Just to check -- you are aware that there is a built in function DiracComb -- so there is no need to approximate it for use in your NDSolve.

Comment: @user64494 OP clearly said that they are trying to plot an *approximate* Delta comb, which is a perfectly well-defined problem. An approximate delta is a smooth function, and there is nothing non-traditional about trying to plot it.

Comment: @bills I am aware, although I am modelling an MRI Scanner which is sending RF pulses so the finite width is slightly more realistic. Thanks everyone for their input, the problem is now sorted :)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: " An approximate delta is a smooth function" has no sense in traditional math. Did you read the cited Wiki articles?

Comment: @user64494 Yes. Did *you* read them? In particular, have a look at the following section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity In particular, what OP is trying to plot is what is usually called a "heat kernel", which is smooth and converges to a Dirac delta in the sense of measures.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Both DiracDelta and that you call  "a heat kenel" are functionals: their arguments are functions, not reals. Of course, locally integrable functions on the reals correspond to certain distributions.

Comment: @user64494 Nope: the heat kernel (and not *kenel*) is a smooth function (a regular distribution, if you will). It is a gaussian function, i.e., it is infinitely differentiable, bounded, and as good as a function can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following, which splits the desired horizontal range into smaller interval chunks and plots each of them separately before combining them with `Show`.

```
With[{interval = 10, range = 120},
 Show[Table[
   Plot[θz[t], {t, i, i + interval}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> None], {i, 0., range, interval}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, range}, {0, 30}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Interestingly, this doesn't work without the option `PlotRangePadding -> None`. That's probably one of the many graphics bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Generally to be sure to get an accurate graph you should aim to have the initial sampling have at least one point in each pit and on each peak (or more precisely in each concave up segment and each concave down segment). You can use `PlotPoints` to achieve that.